# Calling functions from library in PHP and displaying results of the queries

Tags: php, mysql, database, function

I'm trying to merge two queries from two different databases (getting a total from both databases) and display the difference between the two of them in a five column table. 
I have done the functions in a separate library and this is my code:

```
function getFirstTables($conn) {
    $tables = [];

    $q = "SELECT DISTINCT job_processing_table FROM job_type";

    $_tables = $conn->query($q);
    while ($table = $_tables->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tables []= $table["job_table"];
    }

    return $tables;
}


/**
 * This returns a list of all call_report_* tables.
 * $conn: connection to database
 * @returns: list of tables
 */
function getSecondTables($conn) {

    $call_tables = [];

    $r = "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'call_report_%'";

    $c_r_tables = $conn->query($r);
    while ($c_r_table = $c_r_tables->fetch_assoc()) {
        $call_tables []= $c_r_table["Tables_in_spear_reports (call_report_%)"];
    }

    return $call_tables;
}



/**
 * This returns the constructed query for getting test data from spearlinedb
 * $conn: connection to database
 * $startDate: call start time
 * $endDate: call end time
 * @returns: constructed query as a string
 */
function constructFirstQuery($conn, $startDate, $endDate) {

    foreach(getFirstTables($conn) as $table) {

        $sql []= "SELECT 
                number.company_id AS company_id,
                DATE(call_start_time) AS `date`,
                COUNT(*) AS  `sub_total`,
                '$table' AS `table`
                FROM $table
                LEFT JOIN number ON number.id = $table.number_id
                WHERE $table.show IS TRUE
                AND call_start_time BETWEEN '$startDate 00:00:00' AND '$endDate 23:59:59'
                AND $table.processing_complete IS TRUE
                GROUP BY `date`";
    }

    $sql = implode("\n UNION \n", $sql);
    return $sql = "SELECT company_id, `date`, 
                    SUM(sub_total) AS First_total, 
                    0 AS Second_total 
                    FROM ($sql) AS temptable1 
                    GROUP BY company_id, `date`";

}


/**
 * This returns the constructed query for getting test data from reportingdb
 * $conn: connection to database
 * $startDate: call start time
 * $endDate: call end time
 * @returns: constructed query as a string
 */
function construcSecondQuery($conn_2, $startDate, $endDate) {

    foreach(getSecondTables($conn_2) as $table) {
        $company_id = str_replace('call_report_', '', $table);
        $sql_cr []= "SELECT 
                    $company_id As company_id,
                    DATE(start_time) AS `date`, 
                    COUNT(*) AS sub_total 
                    FROM $table 
                    WHERE $table.published = 1 
                    AND start_time BETWEEN '$startDate 00:00:00' AND '$endDate 23:59:59'
                    GROUP BY `date`"; 
      }


      $sql_cr = implode("\n UNION \n", $sql_cr);
      return $sql_cr = "SELECT company_id,`date`, 0 AS First_total, SUM(sub_total) AS Second_total FROM ($sql_cr) AS tempTable GROUP BY company_id, `date`";
```

I want to display the two merged tables with the following columns: company_id, date, total, report_total, difference. Where I am having issues is calling the functions from the separate library. This is the code I have written:

```
$sql = ""; 


echo constructFirstQuery($conn, $startDate, $endDate);;
echo constructSecondQuery($conn_2, $startDate, $endDate);

$result_first = constructFirstQuery($conn, $startDate, $endDate);
$result_first = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);

$result_cr =constructSecondQuery($conn_2, $startDate, $endDate);
$result_cr = $conn_2->query($sql_cr) or die($conn_2->error);


$total_results = array();
while ($row = $result_first->fetch_assoc()) {
    $total_results[$row['company_id']] = $row;
}

while ($row = $result_cr->fetch_assoc()) {
    if(!isset($total_results[$row['company_id']])) {
        $total_results[$row['company_id']] = $row;
    } else {
        $total_results[$row['company_id']]['Reporting_total'] = $row['Reporting_total'];  
    }
}

if ($total_results) {
    echo"<TABLE><TR><TH>Company ID</TH>
        <TH>Date</TH>
        <TH>Spearlinedb Total</TH>
        <TH>Reportingdb Total</TH>
        <TH>Difference</TH></TR>";



    foreach($total_results as $row) {

        $first_total = $row['First_total'];
        $second_total = $row['Second_total'];
        $difference = ($first_total - $second_total);
        echo"<TR><TD>". $row["company_id"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $row["date"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $row["First_total"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $row["Second_total"]. "</TD>";
        echo"<TD>". $difference . "</TD></TR>";
    }
    echo"</TABLE>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

At the moment, when I run the code, I am receiving this error: **mysqli::query(): Empty query in ....**. The functions are running fine on their own and print the queries as strings, but I can't seem to call them in the main code and get them to return the queries as I expected. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction with this please? I am still learning PHP so any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Empty query in` guess the line game, yay!

Comment: @u_mulder Do I get a prize then?

Comment: Surely, you do.

Comment: Sorry, it was in     `$result_first = constructFirstQuery($conn, $startDate, $endDate);
$result_first = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the built query to the `->query()` method as you have confused your variable names.

See edits below

```
$sql = ""; 

//$result_first = constructFirstQuery($conn, $startDate, $endDate);
$sql = constructFirstQuery($conn, $startDate, $endDate);
$result_first = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);

//$result_cr = constructSecondQuery($conn_2, $startDate, $endDate);
$sql = constructSecondQuery($conn_2, $startDate, $endDate);
$result_cr = $conn_2->query($sql) or die($conn_2->error);
```

Comment: may I ask why you are using $sql instead of $sql_cr? Thanks

Comment: Because once you have loaded `$sql` and passed it to the first `->query($sql)` it has completed its function and will never be used again. You can therefore re-use it for the second query.

Comment: You should also consider wrapping these 3 updates in a Transaction. So that if any one fails all of the previous changes will be rolled back, thus keeping your database in a clean state.